# Black background when inserting an image in PDF ITEXTSHARP

Tags: itext, insert-image

I am getting a black background when I insert a image into PDF using ITextSharp version 5.5.8.0 as shown in the image:

[image]

I tried setting a white background but still no impact.
Below is the VB.NET code where I am inserting the image.My goal is to have a white background instead of the black.

```
Dim cb As PdfContentByte = stamper.GetUnderContent(1)
Dim structureeditor As New StructureEditor
Dim temp As System.Drawing.Image = structureeditor.StructureToImage(Me.queryMoleculeTxt.Text)
Dim compoundstructure As Image = Image.GetInstance(temp,    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
' White background is set 
compoundstructure.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.WHITE
compoundstructure.SetAbsolutePosition(30, 150)
cb.AddImage(compoundstructure)
```

Comment: Please share the image itself for analysis.

Comment: Image is created dynamically and when I add the image to the PictureBox it appears good. Do you want me to save the image as Jpeg and send it across.

Comment: Thanks @mkl. You are correct,its the image which is black but when I add that to PictureBox it is displaying with white background. Something fishy but thank you for helping me.